# download generated excel file on the fly after generation

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've created an excel file with phpexcel and successfully save it on the server. but what I really want to do is to say the browser to download this file on the fly. is there any solution for this?
here is my code :

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


        $col = 0;
        foreach ($json[0] as $key => $value) {
            $a = $key;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $key);
            $col++;
        }

        $row = 2;
        foreach ($json as $itemGroup) {
            $col = 0;
            foreach ($itemGroup as $key => $value) {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
                $col++;
            }
            $row++;
        }

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Report');

        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
        try {
            $fileName = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $objWriter->save('/uploaded_images/generatedReports/' . $fileName . '.xlsx');
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example 01simple-download-xlsx.php which shows the headers to set and that you should save to php://output rather than to a "named" file

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location : /uploaded_images/generatedReports/' . $fileName . '.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with the attachment header ?

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_file.xls");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Berofe returning true in try block you have to use header method for downloadable action

$filename ="excelreport.xls";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo "your content \t you next tabcontent \n your next line content \t"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the appropriate headers, and use 'php://stdout' as the output filename.

e.g.

```
$filename = date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'.xls';
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
$objWriter->save('php://stdout');
return true;
```

Comment: whene I use stdout nothing sent back to client

Comment: This is because you need to use `php://output,` not `php://stdout`.